# How to wrap specific text around an image?

Tags: html, css, text, word-wrap

I'm trying to wrap the text around the image but no success.

[image]

```
 <span>Zion Church</span>
    <div><a href="#"><img src="member.jpg"  width="" height="" class="floatleft"></a>
      jffhuhjherwkhrewkhurewyurewyretyunuyrkwugrnhky
      </div>

       img.floatleft {
       float: left;
       margin-left: 15px;
        }
```

Comment: Is that CSS right there in your real code?

Answer (score 1):

The word "jffhuhjherwkhrewkhurewyurewyretyunuyrkwugrnhky" is too long to fit next to the image, so it moves down. If you want to force the word to break, try adding `word-break: break-all` to the CSS for the container element.

Comment: obviously he would not put that long word, it's for testing purpose. :-D

Comment: In actual testing, the code posted works, provided that the CSS code is properly placed in a `style` element. So the explanation seems to be correct: when that “word” is used, it prevents wrapping when the browser window is relatively narrow. Using `word-break: break-all` is, however, almost always a wrong solution; instead, use `<wbr>` and/or `&shy;` in proper places.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
a.imagelink {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
</style>

<span>Zion Church</span>
<div><a href="#" class="imagelink"><img src="member.jpg"  width="" height="" class="floatleft"></a> jffhuhjherwkhrewkhurewyurewyretyunuyrkwugrnhky </div>
```

Comment: Please what do you mean by a.imagelink ?
Is that no meant to be an identifier (id or class)
a.imagelink{

}

Comment: your image is inside a link tag. so we give it a class and set its property. just give it a class name and try it `<a href="#" class="imagelink">`